# Time stamping in multiple cells (making them freeze) base on one cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-timestamp

I'm trying to modify my spreadsheet. Below is my original spreadsheet with the formula I used. Which works great for what I needed. But my boss is wanting time stamps for 3 different actions from column C. This time is frozen and doesn't change unless column C is put to blank then added a new word.

```
=IF(C3<>"",IF(B3="",NOW(),B3),"")
```

[image]

I have used the following formulas for the columns, but I have run into the time changing once column C is changed. Please Help I need these times to freeze.

Formulas used in each column:

```
=IF(C3="ASSIGNED",NOW(),I3), 
=IF(C3="ON SITE",NOW(),J3), 
=IF(C3="COMPLETED",NOW(),K3)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. NOW() is a volatile function, meaning that it changes every time it's recalculated. In order to freeze timestamps, instead of formulas you could use a keyboard shortcuts or Google Apps Script. We already have  a lot of questions about adding timestamps in Google Sheets, please spend some time learning from previous questions. If you need further help, please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have looked all over trying to find something that can help me. I have never used scripts only formulas so I don't know how to even start a script for this.

Comment: To start with scripts, start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, you cannot get a *permanent* timestamp with a spreadsheet formula, even with iterative calculation or a custom function, because formula results get refreshed from time to time. When the formula gets recalculated, the original timestamp is lost.

Search this site for `[google-apps-script] timestamp` to find many examples of timestamp scripts. Also take a look at [yetAnotherTimestamp_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/135269995?msgid=135276870) and [timestampMultipleColumns_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/28719648?msgid=28825318).

Comment: Thank you for the info.

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)